# transform array of nested objects into a JSON like object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary, nested

I've looked many places for this but could not find anything similar. I need to transform an `array` of nested `objects` like this:

```
var currentArr = [ 
  { name: 'Michael',   
    children: ['Lara'] 
  },
  { name: 'Susy',    
    children: ['Mike','Ana','Mary']
  },
  { name: 'Bruno', 
    children: ['Clark']
  }
]
```

into a `JSON` object like this:

```
var result = [
    { 'name' : 'Michael', 
      'children': [
            { 'name' : 'Lara' }
    },
    { 'name' : 'Susy', 
      'children': [
            { 'name' : 'Mike' },
            { 'name' : 'Ana' },
            { 'name' : 'Mary' }
      ]
    },
    { 'name' : 'Bruno', 
       'children': [
            { 'name' : 'Clark' }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have tried using `reduce`, `map` nested but I haven't been able to get this to build how I want it. Specially when looping through the array of strings from `children` where I need to return a mapped result with `name` as a key.

It needs to be nested as the `result` and the `currentArr` would be the entry point.

Comment: `resultObj` should be an array, right?

Comment: `currentObj.map(i => ({name: i.name, children: i.children.map(c => ({name: c}))}))`

Comment: That's not a valid JSON object. The elements of an object are `key: value` pairs, but your top-level object doesn't have any keys.

Comment: @Barmar I was about to make exactly the same observation

Comment: Added to that remark: it is not JSON -- which is a notation, and you do not adhere to it.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(currentObj)`

Comment: anybody who thinks they can answer this as it stands now, can't, because the output that the OP is asking for is impossible.

Comment: The OP now appears to have fixed the question

Comment: @Barmar I thought an array was valid JSON. `JSON.parse('[1,2,3]')` parses it without a problem, heck it even parses numbers, strings, booleans.

Comment: @JuanMendes Look at the edit history. He originally had `{}` around the array, not `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just map over each `children` array and return a new object.

```js
var currentObj = [ 
  { name: 'Michael',   
    children: ['Lara'] 
  },
  { name: 'Susy',    
    children: ['Mike','Ana','Mary']
  },
  { name: 'Bruno', 
    children: ['Clark']
  }
].map(function(item) {
  item.children = item.children.map(function(child) {
    return { name: child };
  });

  return item;
});

console.log(currentObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way leaves the original array unmodified:

```
var result = current.map(function (parent) {
    return {
        name: parent.name,
        children: parent.children.map(function (name) {
            return { name: name };
        })
    };
});

// if you want a JSON string representing the result object
var resultJSON = JSON.stringify(result);
```

Also, as others have pointed out, `resultObj` in your original code snippet is not a valid object. Perhaps you meant for it to be an array?

Comment: It is confusing to speak of JSON at all in this context, as JSON is a notation, and here we deal with objects.

Answer (score 0):

If modifying the current array in place is acceptable, this ES2015 code will suffice:

```
currentArr.forEach(function(p) {
    p.children = p.children.map(name => ({ name }));
});
```

The return value from the arrow function takes advantage of the new ES2015 syntax that says that a bare key inside an object literal without a value takes the current value of the variable of that name, i.e. it's the same as writing `{ "name": name }`

The additional parentheses are necessary to stop the braces from being interpreted as a function body instead of an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```js
var currentArr = [{name: 'Michael',children: ['Lara']},{name: 'Susy',      children: ['Mike', 'Ana', 'Mary']},{name: 'Bruno',children: ['Clark']}]

const map = data => data.map(parent => (
    parent.children.map(
        child => ({ name: child })), parent
))

console.log(JSON.stringify(map(currentArr), null, 4))
```

### NOTE:

Unlike c++ `,` operator in js `,` returns rigth side not left

```js
const data = (1,2,3,4,5,6)

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var currentObj = [ 
  { name: 'Michael',   
    children: ['Lara'] 
  },
  { name: 'Susy',    
    children: ['Mike','Ana','Mary']
  },
  { name: 'Bruno', 
    children: ['Clark']
  }
]

for (var i=0, j=currentObj.length; i<j; i++) {
  currentObj[i].children = currentObj[i].children.map(function(item){return {name: item};})  
}
      
console.log(currentObj);
```